# How to validate multiple $ref in a JsonSchema type property

Tags: .net, json.net, jsonschema

I am wanting to use a Json Schema to validate some incoming Json on a restful web service. But I'm having issues with using multiple $ref's in the type property of the schema.

I need to be able to do this:

```
"type" : [ {"$ref" : "#myObjectRef"}, {"$ref" : "#otherRef"} ]
```

i.e. the object must conform to one of the schemas referenced.

But when I run this through Json.Net using JsonSchema.Parse I get the following error:
"Exception JSON schema type string token, got Array"

I get exactly the same error when trying [this Json Schema](https://github.com/adlnet/tincanschema) for a statement from the [TinCan Api](http://tincanapi.com/) through the Json.Net validator. But the json schema validates against [JsonSchema Lint](http://jsonschemalint.com/).

How can Json.Net handle having multiple type options in the schema? Is there an alternative .net library which will do this validation?

Comment: BTW, have you raised a bug on Json.Net?  That's clearly an error.

Comment: Also, do they only support v3, not v4?

Answer (score 5):

The `type` field in a JSON Schema must be a either a string or an array of unique strings.  These strings can be any of the JSON primitives.

- array
- boolean
- integer
- number
- null
- object
- string

What you need is the `oneOf` field.

```
{
    "oneOf": [{"$ref": "#myObjectRef"}, {"$ref": "#otherRef"}]
}
```

This schema enforces that the object must conform to one (and only one) of the two schemas referenced.  If matching both schemas is also valid, you can use `anyOf` instead.

References

- http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor79
- http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor8